# Is it possible to use the Playstation 4 camera on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: camera, sensor

I want to use a stereo/depth camera with my RPi 4.

The Playstation 4 camera appears to be a stereo camera, and is significantly cheaper at $40 (on amazon) than any others like Intel RealSense, Mynt Eye, Microsoft Kinect, StereoPi, etc.

A cursory search didnt return any hits on RPis and PS4 cameras (though some results for other PlayStation peripherals on RPi 3).

I'm still new to hardware and embedded stuff. Don't really know much about depth sensor hardware. Basically I want to be receiving a stream of RGBD images from 10-30hz video with minimal hacking, and open to suggestions.

Amazon link to ps4 cam: `https://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-4-Camera/dp/B01LW1OM63`

**UPDATE**:

I managed to find some work on integrating the PS4 camera in Linux, following @jsotola's suggestion.

The project does not appear to be maintained any longer, but [PS4eye](https://github.com/ps4eye/ps4eye) appears to be a best-effort attempt at support for PS4 camera on linux.

I found the project from a blog post https://orientalrobotics.blogspot.com/2014/12/playstattion4ros.html (note: Japanese),  with more detailed description of the process and more recent development at the author's fork https://github.com/longjie/ps4eye.

It looks good, but still experimental. I'm probably just going to get the intel realsense.

Comment: `didnt return any hits on RPis and PS4 cameras` ... wrong search ... search `linux ps4 camera`

Comment: @jsotola not sure why I didn't think of this. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

If the camera streams its images over USB or wifi, Yes.  Otherwise, No.